# Get most recent image for my own user through facebook/instagram api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

On my webpage I want to always display my latest instagram post.
I don't want to have the instagram embedded default styling. I just want the image.

Before you could get the most recent image like this:

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=${instagramAccessToken}&count=1

But this way of doing it will be deprecated early 2020.

I know there is a way by using an acccess token, but this has 2 hour timeout. This means that I will have to ask the user to login to facebook / instagram to get an access token. Which is something I don't want.

Is there a way to get latest instagram image without having to log in?

Comment: User tokens can be extended to be valid for up to 60 days … https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing#exchanging-short-lived-tokens-for-long-lived-tokens

Comment: But they still have to login the first time? What about people that don't have facebook/instagram?

Comment: If you want to do this on the client side, then yes, you need to make your visitors log in. But this should better be done on the server side to begin with - so that you can also cache the result, and not have to hit the API again on every single page load. And on the server, you can use _your_ token …